# Checkbox ambiguous behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Application includes Jquery 1.9.1, undescore.js and jquery plagin dataTables.

My checkboxes are wrapped as follows:

```
<label style="top: 3px; position: relative;" class="checkbox" id="IsSpreadCheckBox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="IsSpread" id="IsSpread">
    <span></span>
</label>
```

Element **label.checkbox span** has background images for each case: checked, unchecked, disabled.

Jquery onclick handler for it:

```
$(".checkbox span").click(function () {
    var backgroundContainer = $(this); //span with background image
    var checkbox = backgroundContainer.parent().find("input[type='checkbox']"); //hidden checkbox itself

    if (!backgroundContainer.hasClass("disabled")) {
        if (backgroundContainer.hasClass("checked")) {
            checkbox.removeAttr('checked').prop("checked", false);
            //Also tried checkbox.removeAttr('checked') or checkbox.prop("checked", false);

            backgroundContainer.removeClass("checked");
        }
        else {
            checkbox.attr('checked', 'checked').prop("checked", true);
            //checkbox.attr('checked', 'checked') or checkbox.prop("checked", true);

            backgroundContainer.addClass("checked");
        }
    }
});
```

Also I've got some code for making this element disabled after page loading if needed.

While debugging that works and hidden checkbox element is checked or unchecked correctly (also checkbox image is correct). Moreover, that works fine in target browser **IE 10** (server-side receives correct checkbox value), but in my **FireFox 29** with **FireBug** while debugging on form submit I see:

```
$("#IsSpread").attr("checked") // checked
$("#IsSpread").prop("checked") // false
```

and server always receives **false**.

Debugging on attribute change for this element gives nothing.

If I programmatically makes it checked on **$(document).ready()** it always sends **true** condition.

Thanks!

Comment: `backgroundContainer` is already a jQuery object so you can just use it rather than doing `$(backgroundContainer)`.  How have you hidden the checkbox?

Comment: Take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrvcLsu9/). Is it what you want? It looks like `.prop` works only when element is selected. After reselecting element, `.prop` changes are lost.

Comment: And [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrvcLsu9/1/) with "Send" button. By "element is selected" I mean selecting `var element = $('...')`, changing `element` properties, and then selected again element doesn't have these properties.

Comment: @Regent, Ok I see... It solved my problem now but before it gave me nothing (as you can see under comments). Thank you.

Comment: @Enam you're welcome. So if it is correct, I will post it as answer so that it will not be lost in comments.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrvcLsu9/1/) using `.attr()`:

```
if (backgroundContainer.hasClass("checked"))
{
    checkbox.removeAttr('checked');
}
else
{
    checkbox.attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

and later:

```
$('#send').click(function()
{
    var checked = $('#IsSpread').attr("checked") == "checked";
    alert("Sending " + checked);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrvcLsu9/2/) using `.prop()` (actually it is strange behaviour, but works for me):

```
checkbox.prop('checked', checkbox.prop('checked'));
```

and later:

```
$('#send').click(function()
{
    var checked = $('#IsSpread').prop("checked");
    alert("Sending " + checked);
});
```